# Большое время выполнения DML запросов

Tags: sql, oracle, производительность

Суть проблемы такова что любые операции с бд выполняются очень долго, к примеру:
.      insert into tab1 (time) values sysdate
Выполняется 40-60 мс. А при записи в бд >1000 значений, получаем очень длительную запись. Бд oracle 11gR2 ОС Oracle Linux на CentOs аналогичная проблема. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Оказывается что выгрузка с БД и т.д выполняются почти моментально, проблема только с INSERT (записью в БД)

Всё, что использует родной OCI драйвер (sqlplus, dbForge) отрабатывает нормально, а всё остальное, SQL Net, Thin JDBC (SqlDev, TOAD) тормозит, причём только на DML, и со стороны ДБ время выполненения выглядит нормально.

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

          //  DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            try
            {
                const string oradb = "Data Source = 192.168.137.70/xe; " +
                                     "User id = useridb; Password = user1234";
#pragma warning disable 618
               var con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
#pragma warning restore 618
                con.Open();


#pragma warning disable 618
                var cmd = new OracleCommand {Connection = con};
#pragma warning restore 618



                for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into test (datetime) values (sysdate)";
                    //cmd.CommandText = "Select max(datetime) from test";
                    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();

                   // dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.GetValue(0));
                    dr.Close();
                   // Thread.Sleep(50);
                }



                stopwatch.Stop();
                var averageTime = new TimeSpan(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Запись успешна {0},  {1}", averageTime, dt);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error{0}", e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как у ОС с оперативной памятью, нагруженностью? Много ли места на жестком? Нет ли каких-либо триггеров, навешанных на ту таблицу

Comment: @gil9red оперативы 64 Гб жесткие диски 2 штуки в raid массиве по 1 тб. Свободного места более чем, бд новая и не содержит пока много информации, есть тригеры, но на других схемах и таблицах такая же проблема

Comment: Диски еще чем нибудь эдаким не нагружены ? raid какого типа ? надеюсь оракл имеет прямой доступ к железу, систем виртуализации нет ? Где расположены redo логи и flash_recovery_area ...

Comment: @Mike диски больше ничем не нагружены, raid 1-го типа, да ОС и бд имеют прямой доступ к железу, redo - простите не знаю где глянуть, flash_recovery_area находится в папке где и папка с базой, пример /app/flash_recovery_area  и бд /app/oracle

Comment: Скорость меряете на смой машине в sqlplus или чем ? `select 1 from DUAL` быстро отрабатывает ? Что дает `select value from v$parameter where name = 'memory_target'` ?

Comment: @Mike да и на самой машине и на сторонней, на самой машине через sqlplus, запрос select выполняется быстро, второй запрос дает : Value --- 27111981056

Comment: на дисках есть место вне зеркала, что бы попробовать запись из БД на отдельно взятый диск, а не на зеркало ? ну и для очищения совести 
сделайте с интервалом скажем в примерно минуту два раза `cat /proc/diskstats` интересуют 2 цифры (на сколько меняются) из строки с вашим рейдом, сразу за именем диска и пропустив 3 числа (4е) после него (`x x name ЧИСЛО1 x x x ЧИСЛО2`). просто у меня как то идеи уже кончаются, что может так тормозить.

Comment: @Mike да есть совершенно 2 чистых диска по 1тб не участвующих в рейде, только я не знаю как произвести запись на них. По цифрам провел 3 разных теста строк много но меняется только первая sdc 34609 131402 затем 34615 131821 и 34620 132411

Comment: @Mike может проблема быть с клиентом ? Просто я тоже не понимаю что происходит, и куда копать

Comment: да, диски у вас не загружены. эти числа кол-во операций чтения и записи. и 600 записей в минуту не особо много. ну т.е. видно что что в системе работает, пишет, но у меня например фоновая нагрузка порядка 30 в секунду, пиковая во время бекапов под 200. клиент тормозить так не должен, особенно если вы действительно правильно в sqlplus тестировали. т.е. давали `set timing on; ` и потом делали несколько вставок подряд в тестовую табличку с одим полем, как вы и показали в примере.первая вставка может тормозить, но остальные должны быть вообще мгновенны

Comment: @Mike нет я смотрел немного иначе, не могли бы вы мощность показать как через sqlplus посмотреть ? Какие еще могут быть проблемы ? Тригеры ? Или вьюшки ? Хотя тригеры уже удалял все изминений нет вьюшка есть одна, она из одной таблицы пишет в другую схему и таблицу.

Comment: Разобрался проверил, вообще мгновенно 00:00:00.00

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63257/discussion-between-mike-and-ethernets).

Comment: @Mike да и на тестовой схеме и таблице и на рабочих, симптомы одинаковы, не понимаю что происходит, если учитывать то что в sqlplus выполнения моменальны

Comment: Пока я понял:  всё, что использует родной OCI драйвер (sqlplus, dbForge) отрабатывает нормально, а всё остальное, SQL Net, Thin JDBC (SqlDev, TOAD) тормозит, причём только на DML, и со стороны ДБ время выполненения выглядит нормально. А какой драйвер использует самописное ПО? @Ethernets  было бы неплохо время от времени обновлять вопрос основным из комментариев.

Comment: @0xdb Драйвер взят с клиента установленного с Oracle. На C# родной драйвер, я полагаю что он так же использует библиотеки клиента. Ребят время вопроса закончилось но сам вопрос не решен. Я за выполнение данной задачи готов хоть все баллы отдать )))))) только скажите как ? ))) 23 часа осталось еще ...для выдачи подарка

Comment: @Ethernets Вы можете создать минимальный пример клиента, только коннект и запрос, и опубликовать этот код?

Comment: 0xdb Набросал пример, извиняюсь за задержку

Comment: Я точно не уверен, но. C# не использует ни OCI , ни. SQL*Net, как это делает sqlplus. Т.е. искать надо в стррону - почему клиенты , отличные от "стандартного", отрабатывают медленнее. Сетевые проблемы, хоть и мало вероятно, но полностью исключать рановато. Я бы уже снифером посмотрел, что да как.

Comment: @Ethernets и чем закончилась эпопея? Просто интересно потому, что в моей практике такого не было.

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо за проявленный интерес. Но пока ничем, вашь ответ пока не было возможности опробовать, завтра думаю доберусь (был в командировке, извиняюсь за задержку). Попробовал построить план, так вот ничего там лишнего нет, и в плане запрос выполнился за 1мс. Как сказал выше завтра буду пробовать решение 0xdb. О результатах сразу сообщу. Спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets Вы так и не ответили, пробовали или нет, и что получилось?

Comment: @0xdb Добрый день. Нет, к сожалению не пробовал, т.к. проблема была озвучена руководству и было принято решение перейти на резервный сервер под управлением Win и уйти от Linux серверов в пользу Win server. Именно по этой причине я не закрыл тему, т.к не знаю какой из предложенных вариантов рабочий и эфективен в моём случае.

Comment: @Ethernets Жалко конечно, что вам не удалось попробовать. Может я уж слишком подробно расписал, на самом деле снятъ трасу занимает меньше минуты времени. Подождём, может всё таки кому-то пригодится.

Comment: @0xdb Да очень жаль, надеюсь так же что кому-то это поможет, ваши ответы очень подробные и хорошо описаны. Я бы отдал вам "галочку" но вдруг выход с ситуации в другом ... Надеюсь что люди столкнувшиеся с подобным укажут на верный ответ и я обязательно закрою тему. А пока могу лишь словестно сказать "Огромное Вам спасибо, за помощь и детальное описание".

Answer (score 6):

На то существует ораклевская инструкция `EXPLAIN PLAN`, типа:

```
 EXPLAIN PLAN FOR INSERT INTO TABLE values(10)
```

выдаст вам что происходит, когда вы делаете вставку записи.

Как читать вывод и что делать подробнейшим образом расписано в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231)

грубо говоря, вы увидите где "бутылочное горлышко" - то ли это формируется VIEW или отрабатывает триггер или условие при вставке или что-то еще.

Answer (score 4):

Надо включить SQL трассировку. В противоположенность `EXPLAIN PLAN`, будет показано "то, что уже было", а не "то, что ещё будет". Если и не приведёт к решению проблемы сразу, то даст направление, куда дальше искать.

Для начала надо проверить, включена ли `TIMED_STATISTICS` (по умолчанию включена) и куда пишутся файлы трассировки (обычно `$ORA_BASE/diag/rdbms/orasid/orasid/trace`):

```
select name, value from v$parameter where name in ('timed_statistics','user_dump_dest');
```

Выбираем кандидатов, например сессии на удалённом SQL Developer и SQL*Plus локально на сервере БД:

```
select s.username, s.status, s.sid, s.serial#, sql_trace, s.program, p.spid 
from v$session s join v$process p on s.paddr = p.addr
where s.username = 'SH1';

USERNAME      STATUS          SID    SERIAL# SQL_TRAC PROGRAM                        SPID 
------------- -------- ---------- ---------- -------- ------------------------------ ------
SH1           ACTIVE          139         41 DISABLED SQL Developer                  26596
SH1           INACTIVE         15         92 DISABLED sqlplus@mpsrv (TNS V1-V3)      25930
```

Включаем трассировку под пользователем с DBA привилегиями:

```
exec sys.dbms_monitor.session_trace_enable(session_id=>139, serial_num=>41, waits=>true, binds=>false);
exec sys.dbms_monitor.session_trace_enable(session_id=>15,  serial_num=>92, waits=>true, binds=>false);
```

В выбраных клиентах производим запрос(ы):

```
insert into tab1 (time) values (sysdate);
commit;
```

И выключаем трассировку:

```
exec sys.dbms_monitor.session_trace_disable(session_id=>139, serial_num=>41);
exec sys.dbms_monitor.session_trace_disable(session_id=>15,  serial_num=>92);
```

Находим файлы трассировки в папке `user_dump_dest` (см. выше) и приводим к читабелному виду с `tkprof`:

```
  $ ls -1t *26596.trc *25930.trc
myoradb_ora_25930.trc
myoradb_ora_25507.trc

tkprof myoradb_ora_25930.trc sqlp_25930.prf explain=sh1/sh1
tkprof myoradb_ora_26596.trc sqld_26596.prf explain=sh1/sh1
```

Выход `tkprof` будет выглядеть где-то так:

```
********************************************************************************
count    = number of times OCI procedure was executed
cpu      = cpu time in seconds executing
elapsed  = elapsed time in seconds executing
disk     = number of physical reads of buffers from disk
query    = number of buffers gotten for consistent read
current  = number of buffers gotten in current mode (usually for update)
rows     = number of rows processed by the fetch or execute call
********************************************************************************
SQL ID: f281fbsngrwq0
Plan Hash: 0
insert into tab1 (time)
values
 (sysdate)


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          1          5           1
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        2      0.00       0.00          0          1          5           1

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 151  (SH1)

Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL  (cr=1 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)


Rows     Execution Plan
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  INSERT STATEMENT   MODE: ALL_ROWS
      0   LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL OF 'TAB1'


Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  SQL*Net message to client                       1        0.00          0.00
  SQL*Net message from client                     1        0.00          0.00
********************************************************************************
```

Для сравнения, в SQL Developer заметно значительное ожидание ответа от клиента, т.к. не высокоскоростное соединение с сервером. И кроме того, `SQL ID` отличается, т.е. оракле не распознал запрос как идентичный:

```
********************************************************************************
SQL ID: gck3089qg8n7x
Plan Hash: 0
insert into tab1 (time)
values
 (sysdate)

...    
Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  Disk file operations I/O                        1        0.00          0.00
  log file sync                                   1        0.01          0.01
  SQL*Net message to client                       1        0.00          0.00
  SQL*Net message from client                     1        4.07          4.07
```

Подробнее о других возможностях и чтении форматированного вывода `tkprof` в [документаци](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/sqltrace.htm#PFGRF01010).

Замечу: имеет смысл трассировка в конфигурации выделенного сервера, в случае распределённых серверов очень трудоёмкая задача собирать трассировку, т.к. даже один запрос может быть распарсен в одном сервере, а выполнен в другом.