# ORA-07445: exception encountered

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Кто сталкивался с такими ошибками в Oracle (10.2.0.4)?

1. > ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [_intel_fast_memset.A+44] [PC:0x66D4AEC] [ADDR:0x0] [UNABLE_TO_WRITE] []
2. > ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [clsdcxini+62] [PC:0x66A5EF8] [ADDR:0x18] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []

Comment: Я не сталкивался! Простите, это опрос?

Comment: @Dillinger è morto, не это не опрос, просто может кто сталкивался что это за дрянь вообще!

Comment: В этих примерах не одна дрянь, а несколько. Мне сейчас не очень удобно разбирать по частям ошибки, рассказывая, что значит каждая из них. Как с работы приду, может отвечу. А пока добавлю в фав.

Comment: @Dillinger è morto, ок, спасибо)

Comment: Вот, я вам на скорую руку загуглил: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/763705_1.html - В общем, чето там венда 64 битная, оперативки не хватает, ну и соотвественно, ошибка памяти DB. Как пофиксить - есть на сайте оракл, но я там не зареган, и не могу посмотреть. Если уж вы располагаете такой БД, то наверняка и рега есть на оракле, а значит пофиксить можно. Из фавов вопрос удалю, так как ответил на него в этом комментарии. Удачи в фиксе)

Comment: Да, кстати, вы знали, что для таких баз данных существуют такие ОС, как [tag:Redhat], [tag:CentOS], и так далее? К счастью, ваши венды не предназначены для таких серьёзных дел( Это факт.

Comment: @Dillinger è morto, Спасибо) а на счет оси, так исторически сложилось. оформите ответ!

Comment: Я пожалуй воздержусь  от оформления ответа. Но спасибо за условные +25)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотреть, какие действия необходимы:

```
$  oerr ora 7445
```

> 07445, 00000, "exception encountered: core dump [%s] [%s] [%s] [%s] [%s] [%s]"
>   // *Cause: **An operating system exception occurred** which should result in the
>   //         creation of a core file.  **This is an internal error.**
>   // *Action: Visit My Oracle Support to access the ORA-07445 Lookup tool
>   //          (reference Note 7445.1) for more information regarding the specific
>   //          ORA-07445 error encountered.
>   //
>   //          An Incident has been created for this error in the Automatic
>   //          Diagnostic Repository (ADR). When logging a service request, use
>   //          the Incident Packaging Service (IPS) from the Support Workbench
>   //          or the ADR Command Interpreter (ADRCI) to automatically package the
>   //          relevant trace information (reference My Oracle Support Note 411.1).

Процесс, серверный или фоновый, умер в результате исключения на системном уровне и создан *core dump*. Какой-то единой причины возникновения ошибки нет.

Это внутренняя ошибка, в случае возникновения которой надо обратится в поддержку. 
В данном конкретном случае это уже не имеет смысла, так как 10g уже давно *out of support*.

Дальнейшие действия зависят от того, где эта ошибка произошла и что ей предшествовало. 
Для начала, можно посмотреть лог тревог ALERT.LOG в директории:

```
SQL> show parameter background_dump_dest 

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------------------
background_dump_dest                 string      /app/oracle/diag/rdbms/o10gr2/o10gr2/trace
```

---

Возможно поможет установка патчей (необходима учётная запись на [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=763705.1)):

[BUG:5205552](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=763705.1&id=5205552) - EXCEPTIONAL HIG VM SIZE USAGE FOR ORACLE.EXE ON 64 BIT X86 WINDOWS PLATFORM

> On a Windows 64-bit system, a long running process may fail intermittently with the following set of errors reported to the alert log :
>   ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [clsdcxini+62][PC:0x6515858][ADDR:0x18] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []
>   or
>   ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [ACCESS_VIOLATION][_intel_fast_memset.A+44][PC:0x6544028] [ADDR:0x0] [UNABLE_TO_WRITE] []
>   or
>   ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [unable_to_trans_pc][PC:0x6515858][ADDR:0x18] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []
>
> **SOLUTION**
>   If you are having any or all of the above symptoms, install Patch Set Bundle 23 or above (available as Patch 7353785 to have the fix for Bug 5205552.

Comment: расследование привело к утилите Oracle Trace File Analyzer (TFA), только где ее взять?

Comment: А зачем он вам нужен? TFA ввели с 11.02.

Comment: чтоб разобрать трассировку.

Comment: Попробуйте tkprof.

Comment: через нее тоже можно?

Comment: Ну  да, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701292/%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-dml-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2/709814?s=1|16.8129#709814) уже давал.

Comment: понял. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к [ответу от @0xdb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/898246/211923), с этого стоит начинать анализ любой `ORA-?????` ошибки, хочется добавить описание анализа *критических* ошибок...

На странице поддержки Oracle DB существует [документ `153788.1` для помощи в случае возникновения критических ошибок (`ORA-600`, `ORA-7445`, `ORA-700`)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=153788.1) - в нем в форме поиска можно указать версию Oracle DB и первый аргумент (`_intel_fast_memset` - в вашем случае) ошибки.

MOS (My Oracle Support) нашел один подходящий документ - [`ORA-7445 [memset] (Doc ID 1359594.1)`](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/km/DocumentDisplay.jspx?id=1359594.1), который в свою очередь ссылается на [Bug 20847534 - ORA-7445 Dump with Tag [Application data integrity disrupting] and Called from kgh* Routines on Solaris Sparc Platforms (Doc ID 20847534.8)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1359594.1&id=20847534.8)