# Каким профилировщиком отследить запросы в Oracle

Tags: oracle

Есть приложение, оно общается с базой, как можно увидеть запросы, которое оно отправляет в базу. Напрямую в приложении я не могу увидеть запросы, так как это devexpress.

Comment: Посмотрите [здась](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709814/217579). Надо конечно иметь необходимые права. Подойдёт?

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо за ответ, только у вас в конструкции показаны запросы в виде количества, а мне хочется видеть сам непостредственно запрос, который посылает приложение в базу. В случае когда у меня ADO я это могу делать в случае с профилировщиком для MS SQL. А про оракл, пока не ясно можно ли что то подобное увидеть

Comment: Попробуйте сначало, там увидите полный запрос как он в в базу приходит.